form Electron app: Form fields become disabled after deletion on Windows, but work fine on Mac after form submission
I'm experiencing an issue with my Electron app when executed on Windows that doesn't occur on macOS. It's built as a desktop app. Here's the problem:
When I click the "Delete" button to remove a "transporter" then I click on the "Add button", all form fields become disabled (can't edit anything in this form or any other form of the app -> No focus !). Just to mention that DELETION IS DONE !!! No problem with the delete in sqlite db.
the fields remain inaccessible BUT if I minimize the Electron window and then maximize it again, the fields become accessible when I click "Add" !!!! .
This issue only occurs on Windows; the app works perfectly on macOS.
I've tried several approaches to resolve this, including:

Forcing focus on form fields after deletion
Resetting the form
Checking for event listeners that might interfere
Logging to the console to track the application's behavior

None of these attempts have solved the issue. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening only on Windows and why minimizing and maximizing the window seems to temporarily fix the problem.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest a way to debug this platform-specific behavior in Electron?
Here's a simplified version of my deletion function:
Main.js
ipcMain.handle('deleteTransporter', async (event, id) => {
  const sql = `DELETE FROM transporters WHERE id = ?`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.run(sql, [id], function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error deleting transporter:', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(`Transporter with ID ${id} deleted.`);
        resolve(this.changes);
      }
    });
  });
});

Renderer.js
// Deletion
window.deleteTransporter = function (id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this ?')) {
        window.electronAPI.deleteTransporter(id)
            .then(() => {
                showNotification('Deleted successfully', 'success');
                return loadManageData();  // Reload data after submission
            })
            .then(() => {
                enableAllFormFields(); 
                resetFormState();
                rafraichirInterface();
                logFormFieldsState();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Deletion error:', error);
                showNotification('Deletion error', 'error');
                rafraichirInterface();  // Refresh UI
            });
    }
};

loadManageData() in Renderer.js
function loadManageData() {
        console.log('loadManageData start');
        
        Promise.all([
            window.electronAPI.getTransporters(),
            window.electronAPI.getDestinations()
        ])
        .then(([transporters, destinations]) => {
            console.log('Data retrieved and reloaded');
            
            updateTransporterList(transporters);
            updateDestinationList(destinations);
            
            console.log('UI updated');
            
            // Force a complete rerender
            ///document.body.style.display = 'none';
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.body.style.display = '';
                console.log('Re-rendu forcé');
                
                // Reactivate all fields
                enableAllFormFields();
                checkEventListeners();
            }, 100);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Problem to load data', error);
            showNotification('Problem to load data", 'error');
        });
    }

EnableAllFormFields in renderer.js
// Function to reactivate all fields
function enableAllFormFields() {
    console.log('Début de enableAllFormFields');
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    forms.forEach((form, formIndex) => {
        const fields = form.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea, button');
        fields.forEach(field => {
            if (field) {
                field.disabled = false;  // Reactivate all tags and all fields
                console.log(`Activated element: ${field.id || field.name || 'Without name'}, type: ${field.type}`);
            } else {
                console.warn('Element not defined');
            }
        });
    });
    console.log('Fin de enableAllFormFields');
}

CheckEventListeners in Renderer.js
function checkEventListeners() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('button, input, select, textarea');
    elements.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(`Click on ${el.id || el.className}`));
        el.addEventListener('focus', () => console.log(`Focus on ${el.id || el.className}`));
    });
}




This probably is happening because one system keeps the tab/window persistently loaded while the other is storing/restoring the tab/window contents. The later maybe is causing the virtual data (that is in memory but not cached) to be lost. You may try storing and restoring some disabledForms variable from your localStorage when the events blur and focus are fired, respectively.

After deletion you may try win.webContents.invalidate(); to repaint,work around with your developer tools,see if any property is getting set to fields like 'disabled'

I think problem is in any of the four line of render.js,debug it out by commenting             .then(() => {
enableAllFormFields();
resetFormState();
rafraichirInterface();
logFormFieldsState();
})

try producing most minimal reproducible form of this bug(a separate project with only neccesary things to cause this) you will be able to find cause of this bug on that process,or after that.

I think your problem lies in the deleteTransporter and/or loadManageData function(s).
Note that loadManageData is returning void/undefined because it has no return statement.
Additionally, the deleteTransporter first .then() callback is returning what loadManageData returns (which is actually nothing) and probably this is preventing the next .then() callback from running.
Try returning the Promise in the loadManageData function:
function loadManageData()
{
   console.log('loadManageData start');
   
   // EDIT: Added the return statement to the Promise.
   return Promise.all
   ([
      window.electronAPI.getTransporters(),
      window.electronAPI.getDestinations()
   ])
   .then(([transporters, destinations]) =>
   {
      console.log('Data retrieved and reloaded');
      
      updateTransporterList(transporters);
      updateDestinationList(destinations);
      
      console.log('UI updated');
      
      // Force a complete rerender
      ///document.body.style.display = 'none';
      setTimeout(() =>
      {
         document.body.style.display = '';
         console.log('Re-rendu forcé');
         
         // Reactivate all fields
         enableAllFormFields();
         checkEventListeners();
         
      }, 100);
   })
   .catch(error =>
   {
      console.error('Problem to load data', error);
      showNotification('Problem to load data", 'error');
   });
}

Or adjust the deleteTransporter function:
window.deleteTransporter = function (id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this ?')) {
        window.electronAPI.deleteTransporter(id)
            .then(() => {
                showNotification('Deleted successfully', 'success');
                
                // EDIT: removed the `return` statement from the loadManageData.
                loadManageData();  // Reload data after submission
            })
            .then(() => {
                enableAllFormFields(); 
                resetFormState();
                rafraichirInterface();
                logFormFieldsState();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Deletion error:', error);
                showNotification('Deletion error', 'error');
                rafraichirInterface();  // Refresh UI
            });
    }
};

Try making one correction or the other, starting with the first. I really hope this will work out for you.

Hi I tested it step by step but there's still the same problem :/ UI isn't refreshed. I will check the delete function in details maybe the problem is there.
